# Changing the background color when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is to change the background color when a link is clicked (in this case a list item). When it is no longer clicked, it should revert back to its normal color.

I was able to get this to work via the jQuery `addClass` and `removeClass` methods, but this seems to be hardcoding it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CpnYW/27/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav > li:first-child").click(function(){
      $(this).addClass("highlighted");
      $(".nav > li:nth-child(2), .nav > li:nth-child(3), .nav > li:last-child").removeClass("highlighted");
    });
    $(".nav > li:nth-child(2)").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
        $(".nav > li:first-child, .nav > li:nth-child(3), .nav > li:last-child").removeClass("highlighted");
    });
    $(".nav > li:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
        $(".nav > li:first-child, .nav > li:nth-child(2), .nav > li:last-child").removeClass("highlighted");
    });
    $(".nav > li:last-child").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("highlighted");
        $(".nav > li:first-child, .nav > li:nth-child(2), .nav > li:nth-child(3)").removeClass("highlighted");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opening and closing tags don't match in your JSFiddle.

It's not a good idea to use presentational like `highlighted` for a CSS class name.  It would be better to use `current` or `selected`, and let the stylesheet decide how to indicate which item is currently selected — whether by highlighting, underlining, or whatever visual hint it chooses.

It would be a lot simpler if you removed the `highlighted` class from all items, then added it back for just the selected item.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav > li").click(function() {
        $(".nav > li").removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

nav {
 background-color: #e4801c;
 height: 100%;
}
.nav > li {
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.current {
 background: #faaf5e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                      
          <li>Clients</li>
          <li>Services</li>
          <li>Add</li>
          <li>Time</li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

In addition, I suggest using `text-transform: uppercase` to make the text all caps, as that is also a presentation style choice.

Comment: Also, IMHO the selector `$(".nav > li")` should be saved in a variable and reused whithin the click handler, and the `$(this).addClass` call *may be* replaced with `this.classList.add` (better perf) if the OP don't need to support IE9 and below (http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist)

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't doing it "in javascript", but you seriously should take advantage of all native code that you possibly can --

Just do this in CSS.

Make them all  links, and add a class, such as

```
a.mylink:active { font-style: bold }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having one handler for each element, you can have one for all, that first removes the class on any of the elements that has it, than adds it on the right element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav > li").click(function(){
      $(".nav > li.highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
      $(this).addClass("highlighted");
    });
});
```